# How can I tell if I have a list of File objects?

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I'm working on some drag-drop stuff right now, and as a normalization step I'd like to check if the list of objects I have are actually `File`s. It appears that what I normally get from [`event.dataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) is a `FileList` / `DataTransferFileList`, but the function I'm writing might end up accepting File objects from a non-event source. So, I was thinking about checking if individual items within are instances of `File` or `DataTransferItem`.

However, it seems like what I can actually get out of JS is all over the place. [MDN tells me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) that `DataTransfer.files` contains a `FileList`; Chrome Devtools shows it as a `DataTransferItemList` (in the console). An item within the list should be a 'File', [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), but Devtools shows it as a `DataTransferItem`. Oddly though, `DataTransferItem` is undefined in the Devtools console, and certainly doesn't work for an `instanceof` call. `File`, `FileList`, and `DataTransferItemList` are all there, though.

I haven't even started poking into other browsers yet....

So, my question has two parts:

1. What's with these variations? Does MDN preference Gecko functionality over an interpretation of the W3C spec? Am I seeing Webkit datatypes in the Devtools console, but these datatypes don't necessarily translate to anything accessible (i.e. a JS constructor) in JS that I can use to `instanceof`?
2. How can I tell if something is a list of Files, given all these variations? Should I be relying on some duck typing solution instead of `instanceof`?

Comment: they should have length>0 with elements that are all instances of Blob, and given that, your code should work

Comment: @dandavis `instanceof Blob` works for Firefox and Safari but not Chrome -- Chrome sees them as `DataTransferItem`, and interestingly `DataTransferItem` is not exposed to JS code.

Comment: `DataTransferItem.getAsFile()`. Thanks, Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up with something like this:

```
var knownFiles = [];

// If not already a list, make it a list
if (!files.length) {
    files = [files];
}

// Iterate manually to accommodate Array, FileList, DataTransferItemList
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    file = files[i];

    if (Blob && file instanceof Blob) {
        // Safari, Firefox, IE land here
        knownFiles.push(file);
    } else if (file.webkitGetAsEntry) {
        // Chrome wraps Files in DataTransferItems
        knownFiles.push(file.webkitGetAsEntry());
    }
}

return knownFiles;
```

Most of this came from poking around in browsers (Chrome 41, Safari 8, Firefox 36, and IE 11), but I also had some help from here: https://code.flickr.net/2012/12/10/drag-n-drop/.

Apparently, Chrome is the only browser that bothers with the [`DataTransferItemList` interface](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#the-datatransferitemlist-interface), and that adds an additional layer around `FileList`s and `File`s returned in the `dataTransfer` property of drag/drop events.